# Is it true that $\frac{dw}{w}=-2\frac{d}{dx}(\ln{|y|}).P\,dx$ implies $\ln{|w|}=-2\ln{|y|}\int P\,dx+c$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $y,w,P$ are all functions of $x$. I have arrive at the following
$$
\frac{dw}{w}=-2\frac{d}{dx}(\ln{|y|}).P\,dx
$$
Can I integrate from both sides with respect to $x$ and conclude that
$$
\ln{|w|}=-2\ln{|y|}\int P\,dx+c
$$
Is it valid?
(Edit: $x$ is the independent variable and $P,y,w$ are dependent variables and they are arbitrary functions of $x$.)

Comment: Is $P$ a constant? What are the independent and dependent variables?

Comment: $x$ is the independent variable and $P,y,w$ are dependent variables and they are arbitrary functions of $x$.

Comment: Then the answer is no. Integrals of a product is not the product of an integral.

Comment: @CheeHan Would you like to use that as the answer?